GetBalance faster method and tokens/nft balance
Hello to the whole community!
I have a question about the getBalance function.
given the same node characteristics, if I were to send the getbalance request for 10000 wallets, is the ethers.js or web3.js library faster?
Using websocket in both cases.
Furthermore, is there a way to request the balance of the tokens or nfts (if present inside the wallets) without having to define the contract addresses / abi of the tokens?

While using ethers.js or web3.js library and calling the getBalance() function, the speed depends on various factors such as network conditions, response time of WSS RPC url of the node, etc. I would recommended you to conduct your own benchmarks to determine which one performs better in your specific use case.
Regarding your second question, you can use the this endpoint of Etherscan (or any explorer) API to retrieve the balance of any verified ERC20 token in any wallet.
And this endpoint to retrieve the balance of any verified ERC721 token (i.e., NFT) in any wallet. But, it's available in PRO-plan of the API.
P.S., As, you’ve mentioned:

if I were to send the getbalance request for 10000 wallets

Instead of using getBalance() function of ethers.js or web3.js library, you could also try using this endpoint of Etherscan API to retrieve the ethers (i.e., native token) balance of multiple addresses (you can pass upto 20 addresses per call), and see if this works faster than retrieving using getBalance().

Thank for reply! I've my node in local, so, Is there single request for know if there are any tokens inside wallet?

By local node, do you mean test node like ganache or anvil ?

no, mainnet eth

Actually, it doesn't work to find any tokens inside wallet, but to retrieve the balance of ERC20, ERC721 and native token in the wallet using the endpoints that I've shared, provided that you've the corresponding token contract address in case of ERC20 and ERC721.
